# Rust Actix: Get SystemRunner for System::current()

Tags: rust, rust-actix

Is there a way to get a `SystemRunner` object from the current `System` (which I am getting from `System::current()`). I can't find a way to do it through the documentation, but I feel like it should exist.

I have an endpoint where a user might call a method that uses `block_on`, which requires an instance of `SystemRunner` to run on. I want to avoid calling `System::new("actix")` again and just use the `System` that is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to `block_on` running System.

For tests you can use `block_on` helper in testing tools of `actix-web`: 
 https://github.com/actix/actix-web/blob/master/src/test.rs#L60 that creates local runtime and blocks on the current thread.